# Display different array elements in a loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an array of objects:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 24
            [ban_id] => 163
            [ban_url] => http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/72890.jpg
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 25
            [ban_id] => 162
            [ban_url] => http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/46860.jpg
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 26
            [ban_id] => 169
            [ban_url] => http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/46871.jpg
        )

)
```

I also have a Wordpress loop:

```
$count = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   $count++;
   $show_ad = $count%3 == 0;
   if ( $show_ad ):
      echo '<img src="..." alt="" />';
   endif;
endwhile;
```

I would like to display one (or even more, depends on the user's choice) of the images if $show_ad is equal to true (every 3 posts in this case).

For example, 1 different image every 3 posts :

```
[Wordpress POST 1]
[Wordpress POST 2]
[Wordpress POST 3]
   [Image 0]
[Wordpress POST 1]
[Wordpress POST 2]
[Wordpress POST 3]
   [Image 1]
[Wordpress POST 1]
[Wordpress POST 2]
[Wordpress POST 3]
   [Image 2]
[Wordpress POST 1]
[Wordpress POST 2]
[Wordpress POST 3]
   [Image 0]
...
```

Or another example, 2 different images every 3 posts :

```
[Wordpress POST 1]
[Wordpress POST 2]
[Wordpress POST 3]
   [Image 0]
   [Image 1]
[Wordpress POST 1]
[Wordpress POST 2]
[Wordpress POST 3]
   [Image 2]
   [Image 0]
[Wordpress POST 1]
[Wordpress POST 2]
[Wordpress POST 3]
   [Image 1]
   [Image 2]
[Wordpress POST 1]
[Wordpress POST 2]
[Wordpress POST 3]
   [Image 0]
   [Image 1]
...
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The objects represent the ads?

Comment: Yes they do represent the images (Image 1, Image 2, Image 3...)

Comment: Would you like to show a random ad from your list of objects?

Comment: @battletoilet in fact, I have a wordpress page that contains a number of posts (see the while statement), I want to show the first ad after the 3rd post, the 2nd ad after the 6th post and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing your response, i believe the best way to answer your question is to create an incremental variable as well for your banner ads.

Review the following changes to your while loop.

```
$count = 0;
$banner_count = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   $count++;
   $show_ad = $count%3 == 0;
   if ( $show_ad ):
      //I dont know the name of the banner object so i gave it $banner_object
      $banner_url = $banner_object[$banner_count]->ban_url;
      echo '<img src="' .$banner_url .'" alt="" />';

      //Increment Banner
      $banner_count++;

   endif;
```

Hope that helps! Let me know if your looking for something else. If you only have a certain amount banners, then you may want to reset banner_count when it reaches the end of your banners object. See code below

```
$count = 0;
$banner_count = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   $count++;
   $show_ad = $count%3 == 0;
   if ( $show_ad ):

      $banner_url = $banner_object[$banner_count]->ban_url;
      echo '<img src="' .$banner_url .'" alt="" />';

      //Increment Banner
      $banner_count++;

      //If reached the end of the banner count
      if($banner_count > count($banner_object)) { $banner_count = 0; }

   endif;
```

Comment: And if I have 2 banners to show every 3 posts? how can I do?

Comment: Whats the condition for showing 3 banners? And will all 3 banners display in one iteration of the while loop?

Comment: Yes they will display in one iteration. The condition is a variable. For example $nbrBan = 1; or $nbrBan = 2; or $nbrBan = 3;

Comment: Thanks for putting me in the right direction, everything works well but I had to change the last conditional statement from > to >= otherwise I had an undefined offset error.